# Required field in the fieldsets

Tags: fields, fieldsets

Is there any way to mark the field required by default in the fieldset?

[image]

i want that the required checkbox become non editable.

---

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this can be made non-editable. If you always want this field to be required, you would have to make this field required on Object level (by checking required as true while creating this field). Then, you need to make sure that this field is only used in fieldSets and not in any where else. If you decide to use this somewhere else you will have to provide some value into the field (which may or may not be your business logic).

Coming to the programming part, we also have these two attributes in FieldSets:

1. **DBRequired** - Indicates whether the field is required for the object.
2. **Required** - Indicates whether the field is required in the field set.

You can easily reference these variables in your VF page like this:

`<apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
<apex:inputField value="{!merch[f.fieldPath]}" required = "{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"/>
</apex:repeat>`

where "**fields**" is the list of fields of fieldSets returned by the controller.

A field in a field set can be required by either the field set definition, or the field’s own definition.

FieldSetItem represents an individual field in a field set."isRequired" field is a read only field so we also cannot modify it using apex code.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev for this details, but let me tell your the actual story i just written this post because i'm getting mentioned checkbox as none editable hence i thought, should ask people to achieve this behavior which resolve my problem.

Please let me know if you have any pointer.

Comment: Let me check once

Comment: There must be some issue with user permissions. I checked but I could not replicate the same. I always find this checkbox editable.

Comment: We also raised a SF ticket and they replied that there is some setting in the manifest/meta data file.

Comment: How do we change that?

Comment: no idea what they were supposed to tell us.

Comment: Didn't you ask for an explanation?

Comment: i think issue got resolved by re-creation of managed package :)

Thanks alot for your information.

Comment: Good. Enjoy. :)